# Questioning a disputed flag over an obvious VLQ answer when another in the same question was found helpful

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I have trouble understanding why one out of two answers I flagged as VLQ was disputed  (in the same question).

This one was found helpful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18162630

while this one for [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47658610/1415724) was disputed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18162628

This says a lot about reviewers. Both answers I found were of the same caliber, VLQ.

**On to my question:** What I would like to know is, why reviewers like the ones who said it was OK are (still) even allowed or (feel they are) fit to decline if they don't know what the question is about and how an VLQ answer should be passed off as being acceptable or even answer the question?

*Maybe*'s are comments and shouldn't be posted in the answers area (those 2 answers are now deleted `10k+`). If they can't comment, then they need to wait until they can. If they can't provide a suitable solution instead of informing/advising an OP on how to go about it, then that leaves too much guesswork and too much research to be done, seeing that that question was database related (and email related).

I distinctively remember the OP posting a comment on how to send all that via email; that comment was removed by I don't know who, or why.

I know what I saw, I am not making this up. I may be a lot of things to a lot of people, but **I am honest**.

If what I found were to be VLQ's and continue to be snuck in with their ***"foot in the door"*** answers and them thinking it probably won't be found or flagged, then they've another thing coming. I for one feel that I contribute a lot here (in the php/html/mysql areas, either as commenting and/or answering) and have enough knowledge to say if something is VLQ or not. Both were VLQ's and I will continue to stand by this decision.

Comment: While I agree that both answers are pretty bad, I am unsure what you are asking here?

Comment: @StephenRauch you're unsure. Yeah, so am I about this whole system.

Comment: Well the system, definitely has its challenges, but I am unsure that a better has been designed.

Comment: @Fred If you're getting "sick of it" then maybe you should just take a break from the activity and cool down? No one wants to see your negative attitude and inappropriate words here. You are still required to participate in a constructive and kind manner.

Comment: I've also been somewhat surprised by the "disputed" outcomes on some of my NAA flags. I'm not sure if I can raise a custom mod flag on such a post.

Comment: @NisargShah, in general the mods do not like to get involved in *disputed* votes.  Disputed votes are just that, disputed.  While you, I and Fred, all agree, that those answers should be gone, can we be certain?

Comment: I'm so loving the undelete vote for this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/47658796/1415724 it's a joke. This also says a lot about some of the members here. VLQ doesn't just apply to posts.

Comment: I'm questioning the downvotes my question received.

Comment: and people really need to put their prejudices aside.

Comment: The duplicate that my question was closed with, doesn't answer my question. I know how "that" works, I want to know why reviewers like the ones who said it was OK are even allowed or fit to decline. My question should be reopened.

Comment: After re-reading you question multiple times, I don't see that it's actually asking what you've clarified in your comment.  Although there's no actual question asked, the question appears to be about why one flag was disputed.  Your comment indicates that instead you want to know about the reviewers.  It might help to edit your question to make it _very_ clear what you're asking; comments are ephemeral and your clarification can disappear without any traceability.  Not trying to bust your chops, just trying to make sure that you get the responses that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGaskill you made a very good point about that. I'll edit it a bit later on and hopefully I'd of worded it correctly.

Answer (score 11):

If you look closely, the same people recommended deletion for both answers, and the ones who okayed one of them either also okayed the other one, or simply weren't involved with the other one at all.

So the answer to your question is that different reviewers have different standards. That doesn't say anything about whether those two answers should have stayed or gone, and this is just my personal opinion but I think the answers should be downvoted first (because they're pretty bad) before being deleted (because the answerers haven't responded to review comments and seem uninterested in improving their answers).

What that does say is that you'll find yourself disagreeing with *many* review outcomes, and it sucks, but there's not much we can do. Most of these disagreed-on flags will be resolved as disputed so they're not going to count against you anyway.

Comment: *"and it sucks"* - That's an understatement.